# How do you setup the @MockBean so that @Autowired fields can work?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have a Spring test case but I need to use a mock of the servlet context

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = App.class
)
public class SpringTest {
    @MockBean
    private ServletContext servletContext;
    @Autowired
    private ConfigManager configManager;

    @Before
    public void setupMocks() {
       when(servletContext.getAttribute("foo")).thenReturn("bar");
    }
    @Test
    public void test() { 
       assert configManager.get("foo").equals("bar");
    }
}
```

However, the setup mocks gets called after the autowired (I think) because the test fails.

Is there a different place to do this sort of thing?

The closest workaround I have was to do

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = { App.class, SpringTest.class }
)
public class SpringTest {

    @Bean
    private ServletContext servletContext() {
        final ServletContext mock = mock(ServletContext.class);
        when(mock.getAttribute("foo")).thenReturn("bar");
        return mock;
    }

    @Autowired
    private ConfigManager configManager;

    @Test
    public void test() { 
       assert configManager.get("foo").equals("bar");
    }
}
```

But I didn't like that approach because I have to put SpringTest.class in the context configuration and I have to do more boiler plate code with the `@Bean` stuff.

Comment: Check the ID of the Bean during @Before and the one injected in your class. Maybe your App.class context creates another bean which conflicts with your mock. Usually, you would want the context to be minimal (only the class you test).

Comment: Is there any error at all?

Comment: The error I got was null pointer on the config manager.